# Why is there an underscore in the type name _Recordset?

Tags: delphi

I have code which queries a database, like this:

```
uses Data.DB, Data.Win.ADODB;

// ...

var
  cmd: TAdoCommand;
  r: _Recordset;
  firstName: string;

begin
  cmd := TAdoCommand.Create(nil);
  try
    cmd.ConnectionString := 'Server=dbServer;Database=master';
    cmd.CommandText := 'select FirstName from customers where id=123';
    r := cmd.Execute;
    firstName := '';
    if not r.EOF then firstName := r.Fields.Item['FirstName'].Value
  finally
    cmd.Free
  end

  // ...
end
```

This works but I'm wondering if it's not the ideal way to write it, because of the underscore at the beginning of the `_Recordset` type.  It seems like the underscore is telling me that this type is "internal" in some way and not to be used in standard code.

Is there a more standard way to write this kind of code?  If not, why is the underscore there?

Comment: Probably just to avoid a name clash. Does it clarify if you "Ctrl - left click" on `_Recordset`?

Comment: I was a bit surprised how difficult it was to find complete sample code on how to query a table and iterate through the results.  Sample code on passing in parameters was also hard to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add Winapi.ADOInt to the use clause, you can remove the underscore and use `RecordSet`.

This is because in Data.Win.ADODB we have:

```
 _Recordset = Winapi.ADOInt.Recordset;
```

and in Winapi.ADOInt we have:

```
Recordset = _Recordset;
_Recordset = interface(Recordset21)
```